# UIscrollView swipe gesture + UIButton finger down effect on iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to come up with a UISCrollView in paging mode, where each page shows an image of a product and, besides being able to swipe between pages, I'd also like for the product image to switch to a "down" version of it when a specific product/page is tapped.

So far I tried the following:

**1 - adding UIButtons as the pages of the scrollview:** obviously, this way I can have the images switch to their "Selected" version on finger down, but the buttons, taking up the whole page, prevent the scrollview from detecting the swipe gesture.

**2 - adding UIVIews instead of buttons, and an UITapGestureRecognizer:** this way I can tap an image to select a product and the recognizer also lets the gesture pass on to the scrollview, allowing for swiping too. But the problem with this approach is that I can't switch images to their "selected" versions when the user touches them, since the tap recognizer only reports UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded.

Any ideas as to how to get both the button up/down and scrollview swipe behaviors?

Answer (score 1):

Scrap everything (well not everything, but you get the gist).  No gesture recognizers no nothing.  I recently had this problem too, having mounted a UIView on a UIScrollview that needed to have some interactive elements in it.  The solution, UIView's friggin awesome property called exclusiveTouch.  Exclusive touch takes all of the events from the scrollview, and ignores them if the event is inside the UIView, then passes them directly to your view.  And because UIButton inherits from UIView, all you need is `self.button.exclusiveTouch = YES`

Pretty cool, huh!?